# PHP on var_dump with certain string dumps different string

Tags: php, variables, echo, var-dump

I give the PHP certain string to the var_dump command. But it outputs different string in the browser. First time see something like this, such a strange behaviour. I wonder if it is some security thing or other mechanics...

I tried doing var_dump, echo, var_dump mixed with utf8_encode, utf8_decode... don't remember all the functions

```
die(var_dump('WC"Pk/()@zg?mwUh+hjs\'R5<!#UcA.MJ!?n&ye7<V=H>A[qRb~N[-{6S:ak4yXG`Afd]7f$#e`r%3aU5sb"[vXHhveH-s3W/c+:"'));
```

Actual result in the browser is `WC"Pk/()@zg?mwUh+hjs'R5A[qRb~N[-{6S:ak4yXG`Afd]7f$#e`r%3aU5sb"[vXHhveH-s3W/c+:"`

But it should be `WC"Pk/()@zg?mwUh+hjs\'R5<!#UcA.MJ!?n&ye7<V=H>A[qRb~N[-{6S:ak4yXG`Afd]7f$#e`r%3aU5sb"[vXHhveH-s3W/c+:"` exactly as given in var_dump...

[var_dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03gKC.png)

[strange result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ufoK.png)

Comment: If you print code that contains HTML characters like `<`, why do you expect them to be not executed? Escape them if you want to see them printed

Comment: @NicoHaase it's a password

Comment: So, then such characters can not be escaped to be shown? Sounds strange to me. Why should that be a problem?